# couchbase merge array to sub-document

Tags: python-3.x, couchbase

I have to merge an arry to couchbase key-value array ,I have read the [document](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/subdocument-operations.html), that is only this:

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster,PasswordAuthenticator
import couchbase.subdocument as SD
#other thing
bucket.upsert("all_goods",[])
bucket.mutate_in("all_goods",SD.array_append("",["a","b","c"])
bucket.mutate_in("all_goods",SD.array_append("",["１","２","３"])
```

I hope get that

```
all_goods => [a,b,c,1,2,3]
```

but ,I got this:

```
all_goods => [[a,b,c],[1,2,3]]
```

I hope to merge the array in to the document

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/subdocument-operations.html) this is the expected behaviour:

```
bucket.mutate_in('my_array', SD.array_append('', ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3'])
# the document my_array is now ["some_element", ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"]]
```

As a workaround I will suggest to create an array and `extend` it and later do the `array_append`:

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster,PasswordAuthenticator
import couchbase.subdocument as SD
#other thing
bucket.upsert("all_goods",[])
my_array = ["a","b","c"]
my_array.extend(["１","２","３"])
bucket.mutate_in("all_goods",SD.array_append("",my_array)
```

Or you can append the elements individually:

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster,PasswordAuthenticator
import couchbase.subdocument as SD
#other thing
bucket.upsert("all_goods",[])
bucket.mutate_in("all_goods",SD.array_append("","a","b","c")
bucket.mutate_in("all_goods",SD.array_append("","１","２","３")
```

Comment: yes, It is a good idea, however  ,I have  to upsert a big document (about 18.4 MB), upsert  on one time will make a timeout error , the length of the array is too long ,I have to upsert it many times

Comment: In that case I will suggest to review the documentation and check if there is something that can help you...